# homotopy can't extend to one point compactification.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f,g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the functions $f(z) = z^n$ and $g(z) = z^m$, $n\neq m$.  Taking the one point compactification both of these functions extend to continuous functions $ f^1, g^1: \mathbb{C}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^1$ where $\mathbb{C}^1 = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ and $f^1(\infty) = g^1(\infty) = \infty$.

In the complex plane, there is a linear homotopy $F:\mathbb{C}\times I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ from $f$ to $g$ given by $F(z,t) = (1-t)f(z) + tg(z)$. We can then define a map $G:\mathbb{C}^1\times I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^1$ by $G(z,t) = F(z,t)$ and $G(\infty,t) = \infty$. **I want to know why this cannot be a continuous map using basic point-set topology.**

My thoughts: The map's restriction to $\mathbb{C}$ is clearly continuous, so something fails on the set $\infty \times I$. Let $K_N = \{z\in \mathbb{C}| \,|z|\leq N \}$ then $U_n = K_n^c$ is an open neighborhood of $\infty$, and I think these sets are a neighborhood base so the function should fail to be continuous on one of these.

(I can't seem to write \hat in latex, anyone know how to fix this?)

Comment: Ok, I see one way to do this: I can make a cauchy sequence whose image under $G$ isnt a cauchy sequence anymore. Take $x_i = (i,1/i)$ when $i$ odd, and $=(i,0)$ when $i$ is even.

Comment: One remark on the boldface line, not every tool is fit for every task. You can't make a toast with a screwdriver (but you can with a hammer if you're extra-creative). Point-set topology can't, and won't, solve all the questions about topology. Sometimes it will solve questions in an extremely complicated way that algebraic topology (or other tools) will solve easily. Sometimes it is the other way around. Sometimes topology is the wrong tool to begin with (e.g. when making a toast). As for this particular question, it might be reasonably solvable with point-set topology. Maybe... I don't know.

Comment: Haha, i've heard its good at making bagels though. The thing is, this came up while trying to make homotopy arguments to show that the degree of a polynomial as a map $S^2\rightarrow S^2$ is the same as its degree in the usual sense (Hatcher, section 2.2 exercise 8).

Comment: I can see ways to do this with intersection theory too, but the point is that I wanted to see what was happening with the maps themselves that obstructed continuity, not just to get the result.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you 100% though.

Comment: Wait, my Cauchy sequence argument should be wrong, it uses the topology on $\mathbb{C}$ instead of the one point compactification. I am unconvinced again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking to disprove the claim that

$$ \lim_{z \to \infty, t \to t_0} F(z, t) = \infty$$

The usual method is to approach the point from multiple paths. Let's boldly assume there is a path where the limit would come out to zero. Let's be even more bold and say the function is identically zero along the path.

Along such a path, we have $t = 1 / (1 - z^{m-n})$ (or, if $z^{n-m} \neq 1$ and some conditino I haven't worked out).

It's easy to find such a path now: just choose $w$ so that $w^{m-n}$ is a negative real number, and let $f(x) = w^{m-n} x$ where $x$ is a real number, and let $x \to \infty$.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} F(w x, 1 / (1 - (wx)^{m-n})) = 0 $$

which is not the value of $G(\infty, 0)$.

Comment: Ok, this is good! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This function is much more strange than I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebraic topology, it is easy to prove that there is no homotopy between $f$ and $g$ by comparing the degree of the induced homomorphisms between the homology groups of $\hat {\mathbb C}$. If you want to get to the core of why the homotopy $F$ you defined cannot be extended, then point-set-topology will do it.

Assume that $G:(\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\})\times I\to\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is a homotopy that fixes $\infty$ and extends $F$. By the universal property of the quotient space $Q$ which identifies $\{\infty\}\times I$ to a point, it induces a continuous $\hat G:Q=(\mathbb C\times I)\cup\{\infty\}\to\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, where the domain actually carries the compactification topology which coincides with the quotient topology. Now a map between locally compact Hausdorff spaces $f$ can be extended to a map $\hat f$ between their one-point-compactifications if and only if $f$ is proper, i.e. the preimage of a compact set is compact.

We'll see that $\hat G|_{\mathbb C\times I}=F$ is not proper, because the preimage of $\{0\}$ is not bounded:
Let $n>m>0$ in $\mathbb N$. There is a $\phi$ such that $(n-m)\phi=\pi$. Define $z=re^{i\phi},\  r>0$. We have $z^n/z^m=r^{n-m}e^{i\phi}=-r^{n-m}$, so $z^n=-r^{n-m} z^m$. You want $tz^m+(1-t)z^n=0$ which implies $t/(1-t)=r^{n-m}$. So no matter how big $r$ is, there is always a $t\in(0,1)$ satisfying this equation.